# When to add -ist and -er suffix

Tags: suffixes

Is there a reason as to why certain roles end in different suffixes, like -ist and -er?

For example, why can't a runner be a 'runnist'? Or an artist to 'arter'?

Comment: related, but more specific: [Raper vs. Rapist; Why the shift in suffix?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168352)

Comment: The following question seems nearly the same, but I don't know if the answer really addresses your question. The answer gives a description of the etymology and general usage, but as far as I can see, no clear criteria for determining when to use one vs. the other: [Whats the difference between “-ist” and “-er”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235958)

Comment: A *runner* is *one who runs*; a *runnist* would be one who (prolly politically) *advocated the idea of running*…